# can i perform xml operations in XMLLITE with the same features of MSXML?

Tags: xml, msxml, xml-parsing, xmllite

I know something about MSXML parser ,to create an xml with native code ..Msxml depends COM..So I want to create xml without com and dom ,so i wish to choose XMLLITE..but i dont know full details about xmllite ,when i was read the xmllite documentation in msdn ,i gathered some points ,they will provide only 2 things (IXMLReader & IxmlWriter).Here in msxml ,i had many functions to do xml operations ,such as selectsinglenode,appendchild ..Now can i perform the same things with XMLLITE?..please give me the right choice towards this ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSXML has a rich set of features, e.g. DOM 1.0 (you can manipulate the DOM tree with appendChild etc), SAX 2.0, XPath 1.0 (selectSingleNode etc) and XSLT 1.0. In addition MSXML supports XSD 1.0 and DTD validation. MSXML is provided as COM objects.

Unlike MSXML which supports DOM the in memory tree model and SAX the push model parser, XmlLite provides the pull model parser which is really fast with limited footprint. XmlLite is provided as pure C++ library. Unfortunately, it does not support DOM, XPath, XSLT, XSD and DTD validation, though DTD entitiy is supported in terms of custom resolver.

So the choice depends on your requirement. I would use XmlLite if it satisfies my needs, but I don't think COM is burden for me to adopt MSXML solution. There is really nothing wrong with COM itself.

Comment: One of the very few of your questions I've been able to upvote. Guess what it does not mention? There's a connection there.